# Rails 5: attachinary larger thumnails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary + [Attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) to upload images to my projects. After I select an image to upload, attachinary creates a thumbnail preview of uploaded image. The question is: There is some way to get these thumbnails preview with a larger quality? By default the thumbnail has 75x75px, can I control it?

Thanks!

Comment: If it suits you could you mark it as the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

the default thumbnailing is defined [here](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary/blob/98a895be22edc74b1928ffa3ae116d24bd9818fd/lib/assets/javascripts/attachinary.js.coffee#L19) and goes like this :

```
src="<%= $.cloudinary.url(files[i].public_id, { "version": files[i].version, "format": 'jpg', "crop": 'fill', "width": 75, "height": 75 }) %>"
```

You would need a PR to make this flexible and generic for anyone but for your own testing needs you can just fork the gem change the values and see if it fits. You will need to change the Gemfile configuration to point to the fork of the gem you did